# JavaScript for Dapp

Tags: dapps, javascript

Can the following libraries and frameworks be used to build the Client-Side of DApps ?

Specially

- Ember
- Backbone
- Aurelia
- Polymer
- jQeury

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the options are correct. The problem is that as soon as your smart contract becomes more complex and large, it's even harder to control it with plain JS or even the other frameworks mentioned before.

Nowadays, **one of the most emergent languages is Reactjs**. 
It's **async syntax is very intuitive** and is so easy to work with it if you're familiar with JS.

The nice things are the **state and component methods**. It will let you query the blockchain continuously, by async methodology and update the state to show on the DOM the correct variable values/states of a contract etc..

Here you have a bit extra documentation to introduce yourself:

- http://truffleframework.com/boxes/react 
  Unboxing the React Truffle Box provides you with a React based Ethereum Smart Contract. There are other React boxes available too for Redux and UPort.
- https://reactjs.org/  Here you have the React documentation and also lots of examples that will be so useful to you.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the smart contract is simple then you could even go with just plain javascript. I'm using angular.io and it looks good enough for the job.